# What is the colon (:) in Emacs lisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm not talking about keyword variables (those that are [prefixed with a colon](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Symbol-Type.html)), I'm talking about just `:`. Example from an `ielm` session:

```
ELISP> :
:
```

It seems to be a variable whose value is `:` which makes it sort of act like a noop [like it does in shell](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html). I'm just curious if there's any documentation about it. I can't look it up with `describe-variable`...

Comment: The reason its value is itself is precisely the fact that it is a keyword. :-) All keywords share this property.

Comment: @Malabarba: But not everything that is self-evaluating (constant) is a keyword.

Comment: @Drew indeed! Well added.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`:` is a *keyword*, that is, a Lisp *symbol* whose print name begins with ":". It satisfies predicate `keywordp`.

Comment: mgalgs: And as a complement to Drew's comment in your own answer, see also the explanation at `C-h i g` `(elisp) Constant Variables` `RET`.

Comment: mgalgs: Actually, that node was linked directly from the URL you gave yourself in the question, so presumably you'd read it already. Note that you will often see code using keywords as a "more-descriptive than `t`" value, where a function simply calls for a non-`nil` argument.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Looks like it's just a variable whose value is `:` after all.</s> I can't look it by calling `describe-variable` interactively but I can look it up with `(describe-variable :)`:

```
:'s value is :

Documentation:
Not documented as a variable.
```

Edit: no, it's not a variable.  See the accepted answer.

Comment: not a variable. a symbol, yes. a keyword symbol, yes. not a variable.

Comment: @nicferrier: A symbol that has a `symbol-value` is a variable, so yes, you might say that it is a variable too. However, it is a *constant* symbol. Note, for instance, that `defconst` is covered in `(elisp) Defining Global Variables`. But of course `defconst` does not define a real constant; the value can be changed. (Whether Lisp constants should be called variables is another question.)

Comment: Whoa. I disagree. The value cannot be changed. The constant definition can be re-evaluated. A constant can be redefined. And I also disagree that : is ever a variable. It's a self quoting symbol.

Comment: @nicferrier - does a _keyword symbol_ have a parallel in another language? e.g. is it like/equivalent to a Ruby `:symbol`?

Comment: idk about Ruby, seems like it might. But keywords are just self quoting, interned strings. So their value is their name.